# jQuery: Variable not defined within my hover()

Tags: jquery, variables, hover, undefined

I have this code:

```
$('#services_list > div').hover(function() {

    var serviceHoveredOn = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    $(serviceHoveredOn + ' .service_expand').stop().animate({'width': '169px'}, 150);

},

function() {

    $(serviceHoveredOn + ' .service_expand').stop().animate({'width': '159px'}, 150);

});
```

But, `serviceHoveredOn` is not defined when I hover outside of my `div`. I searched and found this:
[jquery: passing variables in hover() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287324/jquery-passing-variables-in-hover-function)
But I am not sure how I can use toggle() to solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access variables declared in another function.

---

In your case, you don't even need it. Just use `this`, and pass it as a context:

```
$('#services_list > div').hover(function() {
    $('.service_expand', this).stop().animate({'width': '169px'}, 150);
},
function() {
    $('.service_expand', this).stop().animate({'width': '159px'}, 150);
});
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I didn't know that I could use `this` like that. Would you mind explaining what that's called so I can look it up?

Comment: `$('.service_expand', this)` is equivalent to `$(this).find('.service_expand')`. It's called "the context". See [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1).

Comment: Ah, I knew about `.find` but I didn't even think about using it. This way is even simpler though. Much appreciated.

Comment: better to do `$(this).find(".service_expand")...`

Comment: @epascarello - Why? I think the context method might even be more performant. And don't tell me that `find` is clearer. Once you get used to using the context, it's just as clear.

Comment: @epascarello - Well, [I was wrong about the performance](http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-method-vs-context-method). Still, I consider the context method much cleaner.

Comment: The context selector spins up two jQuery objects, hence why slower.